# Minimum number of lookahead tokens to parse JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

What is the minimum number of tokens of lookahead a parser for JavaScript would need?

I couldn't find this in the spec https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/, though the spec mentions lookahead sets a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Any language which can be parsed with finite lookahead -- that is, with an LR(k) parser for any fixed `k` -- can be parsed with an LR(1) parser. So it is not really necessary to make that claim in the standard.

Having said that, for all the versions of ECMAScript I've attempted to parse, it has been quite straight-forward to produce a one-token lookahead parser from the grammar.